# UISegmentedControl with Image and Title

Tags: ios, uiimage, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a custom UISegmentedControl with 2 sections and it is declared programmatically so I cannot use IB.  I set a background image, tint, and a title.  I need to have an image display in line with the title.  If i set the image, the title disappears and vice versa.

I need a way to display both an image and the title in line on the segment.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Plz refer this link..hope it works perfect.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457876/uisegmentedcontrol-with-image-and-title

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subclass of UISegmentedControl, overwriting

```
[MySegmentedControl initWithItems:] 
-(id) initWithItems:(NSArray*)items {
    [self setImage:anImage forState:aState barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setTitleTextAttributes:aDict forState:aState];
    [self setDividerImage:anImage forLeftSegmentState:aState rightSegmentState:aState barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    ... do more UI stuff ...
}
```

And in your view controller, you call it with:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [self.view addSubview:[MySegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:@[@"one",@"two"]]];
    ...
```

works for me reliably for iOS6/7.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming segmentedControl is in your .h as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
```

Do this in your .m for your viewController and set up the segments in code

```
[self.segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Title with Image" atIndex:0 animated:YES];
        [self.segmentedControl setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"whatever.png"] forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: No, it does not work.  I was in error.  You may want to try this one on github -> [https://github.com/u10int/URBSegmentedControl